# how can i pass two interaction ticket number in HPSM rest url

Tags: rest, web-services, servicemanager

This is my Rest URL:

```
http://serviceIP:servicePort/SM/9/rest/interactions/TicketNumer1
```

It will return all information of TicketNumer1. How can i add TicketNumer2 into same URL and fetch both tickets information at same time? According to HPSM service document, I tried by putting comma(,) between tickets number but it didn't work.

Comment: That isn't REST. From an `interactions` resource, you should get an interaction back, not ticket numers (whatever a numer is). Replace `TicketNumer1` with `{id}`, which is the ID of the interaction you want to access. From there, you may get the `tickets` resource and once you got that you just query all ticket IDs such as `/interactions/{id}/tickets?ticketId={id1}&ticketId={id2}`.

Comment: hi, i tried it but still gives only one ticket id information not other. it would be great if you could please explain more. thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you tried and what else you require. I don't know HPSM. If it is an API you use, then I suggest to go through the documentation or contact the distributor.